# Reading a Wordpress function description

Tags: wordpress

I want to be able to understand the standard function description that is provided for Wordpress functions. In particular, could someone explain the following example from [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories):

Usage

```
<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
```

Default Usage

```
<?php $args = array(
    'show_option_all'    => ,
    'orderby'            => 'name',
    'order'              => 'ASC',
    'show_last_update'   => 0,
    'style'              => 'list',
    'show_count'         => 0,
    'hide_empty'         => 1,
    'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
    'child_of'           => 0,
    'feed'               => ,
    'feed_type'          => ,
    'feed_image'         => ,
    'exclude'            => ,
    'exclude_tree'       => ,
    'include'            => ,
    'current_category'   => 0,
    'hierarchical'       => true,
    'title_li'           => __( 'Categories' ),
    'number'             => NULL,
    'echo'               => 1,
    'depth'              => 0 ); ?>
```

I can guess most of it, but in particular I can't guess:

- What does blank after the comma mean? Empty string?
- What is the __?
- How do I call the function? Keyword like python, positional arguments or do I have to pass an array?
- Is there anything else about Wordpress function descriptions which isn't covered in this example?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- that trailing comma would be a parse error - in that documentation, I believe it is just showing an option value with no default.
- the __() function is a [language localization function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress#Localization_Technology), which takes an English language literal string, and returns the a translated string for an application-defined locale.
- the function is called by passing in an array as a parameter, defined as detailed. In fact, internally this uses [wp_parse_args](http://xref.yoast.com/wpmu-2.7.1/wp-includes/functions.php.source.html#l2461) which allows you to pass an array, an object, or a urlencoded style string of options.
- please note this is just an *idiom* rather than the way all [PHP functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php) are called. In this case, most likely the designer of the function wanted a wide range of optional arguments, coupled with the ability to add new arguments without breaking older code.

Comment: The function doesn't actually take an array, but a string. For example wp_list_categories('exclude=4,7&title_li=') sets exclude to the list list(4,7) and title_li to null

Comment: Looking at the wordpress source code, it can take an array with the given keys, an object with the given member variables, or a urlencoded style string.